# How can I pass a list of unit test python file names(path\test.py) to nose.run() method to execute all the tests in all these files?

Tags: python, nose, python-unittest

I have a list of python file names(name includes absolute path.. eg-folder1\test1.py). Each of these files contains a set of unit test cases. I want to pass this list to nose.run() method so that all the tests in these files can be executed. Can anyone help me with the python code for this.

The files in the list need not be from the same folder. Absolute file path is given along with each file name.
It would be helpful if the result of nose.run() can be saved.(not a mandatory requirement)

Comment: The way we do it at work is to use a bash script that simply calls nose on each of the directories we want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run the tests if all of them are in same folder as follows

```
nose.run(argv=['folder', 'test_suite1', 'test_suite2'])
```

Where `folder` is the folder where both `test_suite1.py` and `test_suite2.py` are present.

And to capture the result of the run, I use '--debug-log' argument. So your final command becomes,

```
nose.run(argv=['folder', 'test_suite1', 'test_suite2', '--debug-log', '/home/loglocation/logfile.log'])
```

I didn't spend much time in terms of how to run if the test suites are in different location.